# Indian Army supply of Alcoholic beverages?

Tags: taste, recommendations, storage, alcohol-level, rum

Indian Army cantonments are supplied all kinds of alcoholic beverages. These supplies are only for army men. Do the drinks strengthen their guts?

My question is: Are the manufacturing special and tastes separate from products sold in the market. Is the reason subsidy or because the drink is strong. Are the supplying companies special for armies?

Comment: Please specify which army you're asking about.

Comment: @Xander- I am asking about INDIAN ARMY. user-37920

Comment: I don't think the suppliers are different. The prices are cheap because they don't have to pay some tax. It goes for other products as well not just alcoholic drinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Indian Army supply of Alcoholic beverages?**

Are the supplying companies special for armies?

Regardless of which national forces (army) one is in, the main reason for suppling some for of booze is to boost troop moral.

Generally supplies will be obtained by local sources as best possibly done. There are no supplying companies special for armies? Local conditions and local economies will influence the army’s decision on what type of boozes to buy for the troops.

The Romans had wine rations for their troops. That became rations of beer in northern countries.

Wine was give to the French troops in World War I.

> It was Arnold Zweig, German anti-fascist writer and WW1 volunteer, who said that it was possible for a man to fight a war “without women, without ammunition, even without strongpoints, but not without tobacco and not at all without alcohol.”
>
> Forces on both sides of the war appreciated this fact: for the maintenance of troop moral, alcohol had an important part to play.
>
> And beyond the tenches, the social and cultural impact of the war would sound the beginning of the 20th Century, and with that, the cocktail boom that would help to define the inter-war years in Europe.
>
> So, from the trenches of three of the major protagonists and two cocktail innovations that are enjoyed to this day, we have assembled the top five drinks associated with the Great War.
>
> When France went to war in 1914, troops were only issued water, but the army quickly began issuing a daily wine ration as early as September 1914.
>
> This consisted of Pinard (a word whose english equivalent would be “plonk”), which was a low-quality red wine. Generally, soliders were issued with ½ liter of Pinard per day, but this could fluctuate depending on the logistical situation.
>
> Soldiers were sometimes issued beer, cider, or brandy in lieu of Pinard, but it remained the most common alcoholic drink consumed at the front.
>
> On special occasions, other drinks like spiced wine or sparkling wine would be issued. Pinard was sometimes mixed with brandy; some reports mention it even being mixed with ether.
>
> Better quality wine, Cognac, and other brandies were also widely available behind the lines, particularly in cafés and brothels catering to soldiers. - [Top Five World War One Drinks](https://www.thedrinksbusiness.com/2014/11/top-five-world-war-one-drinks/)

Supply and demand for alcohol for troops will vary according to region and economic situations involved, this includes the Indian Army.

> [**Why is liquor drinking encouraged in the Indian Armed Forces?**](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-liquor-drinking-encouraged-in-the-Indian-Armed-Forces)
>
> 1. As others have pointed out only tax is not charged and limited supply is given.
> 2. Rationed liquor ie in small doses is good for health.
> 3. Liquor helps in relaxation and also frees mind from stress of daily hard routine.
> 4. Liquor high reduces self-censorship so that many times it allows the person to loosen up his feelings clamped up inside. This is like a release valve of pent-up stress. Within limits such regular dispersal of stress is a good thing. Though out of limits it can lead to creating situations which will actually lead to more stress. Given the strict discipline and obedience required in army it might help unwinding from stressful situations.
> 5. Why alcohol helps with stress : As per Ayurveda wine and alcohol are classified extra sweet (not in taste but in after-effect on mind and body). They bring sweet taste to life. Many times people get addicted to this sweet effect of alcohol. For example in Ayurveda alcohol addicts are advised to slowly reduce and replace alcohol with sweet smell, sweet taste, sweet music, sweet warmth, sweet emotions of love, comfort, safety and caring etc. This helps reduce the withdrawal symptoms and slowly wean away the dependence on alcohol.
> 6. It’s not very surprising that people who lead a hard and stressful life away from comforts of family and civilian life need a bit of sweetness in their life as well. It comes in a bottle and can be had in limited quantities on demand.
> 7. Not all postings are on border or troubled areas. Also not all army men are involved in military field operations as some may be in administration or teaching or other duties. Still the traditions of British times may have continued irrespective of type of work.

The Indian Army will acquire their provisions of alcohol, like all other armies, locally if possible and at the best price possible.

War is hell, and soldiers need a little lift from the misery of their life style. **It is more a question of maintaining good troop moral!**

The Russians love their vodka, the French their wine and the Indian troops love their rum.

Answer (score -1):

I have a couson who is an officer in the Indian ARMY on the Assam Rifles Regiment. So everytime when he came home he would always take home a very special class of beer and alcohol. Yes they can get as many as they want he said. Sometimes he would even get a full suitcase pack everytime he is on leave. He said that alcohol is consumpt strictly, and getting drunk while on duty is forbidden. He himself would never drink except only when he took a leave at home.  I don't think its any different from what they sold locally but one thing I know is that it is expensive in the market. I am unsure of what brand it is because he would take home different kinds, one of his favorite one is Little Bay?, Budweiser Beer white kind, Aberlour whiskey which is like 7000 rupees in local market in India. So i am assuming it is definitely a good quality whiskey. Maybe the officers can have a better choice? i am unsure.